# My regex works in the VS Find&Replace but NOT when compiled

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2012, replace

I have a regex, which is `@"\{ImageSource = imageURIs\[(\d*)\]\} //(.*)\s$"`.

It matches lines like `{ImageSource = imageURIs[123]} //whatever_goes_here`, which works BRILLIANTLY in the VS Find&Replace box, but NOT when put into C#. However, wait: they have the same engines! [MSDN link, top line!](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2k3te2cs.aspx)

Could you please help me? I think everything's escaped (the brackets that aren't are needed: I'm using them as groups!) and also I can't do all my work within the VS F&R, as I'm merging it with another list of things.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it that final `\s` that's breaking things?  Should that really be there, forcing it to only match lines with trailing whitespace?

Comment: Does happen, but it has trailing whitespace in VS but not when I Regex it. Oh wait, I forgot I trimmed the line. Stupid. Thanks! Will accept in 11 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Without your actual files to match lines with, this can be quite difficult.  But, here's a potential change.  (Notice the lazy `.*?` and the `\s*` changes near the end.)

```
@"\{ImageSource = imageURIs\[(\d*)\]\} //(.*?)\s*$"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the `RegexOptions` default value does not imply `Multiline` (see [Regular Expression Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs.aspx), the **Default Options** section), it means that `$` will match the end of the **input** and not the end of **each line**.
Besides, the `.` (dot) will not match `\n` without the option `Singleline` (see [RegexOptions Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx)).

So you can try *playing* with the options, maybe in your case `Multiline`.

Comment: Foreaching its line and already got an answer, thanks though :)